# Custom Search for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I would like to create a custom search in an iPhone using a UIWebView.

Example: Replace `{query}` in the line below with what the user has typed in.

URL:
`http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={query}&submit=search`

**Final Code:**

```
[super viewDidLoad];
_webView.delegate = self;
NSString *queryString = _searchField.text;
NSString *request2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%@&submit=search", queryString];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request2]];

[_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Comment: You can create your own URL strings and pass them into a UIWebView!

Comment: I think the string problem is going to be followed by the lack of conversion to an NSURL type within your call to NSURLRequest.  Look at my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%@&submit=search", @"USER ENTRY"];
```

Comment: From the String perspective, I think this is the BEST answer, as it will necessitate less actual NSString allocations.

Answer (score 1):

NSString gives you the method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` which you can use:

```
NSString *request = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{query}"
                                                        withString:queryString];
```

NSMutableString has similar methods for modifying a string in place.

**Note:** There are two r's in "Occurrences" -- I'd originally misspelled that. This is the source of the error you're getting -- you have to spell the method name correctly.

Comment: This is my code so far it is giving me the error:No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector ''stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:'

Comment: See the note I added. You have to spell the method name correctly.

Comment: It will now build and run but when I type text into the UISearchbar then when I Press the search button and it quits.

Comment: @s0ulp1xel Okay... why does it do that? Is it your contention that substring replacement is broken in NSString, or do you think the problem lies somewhere in your code? What error message(s) do you get? Are you dereferencing a bad pointer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to be converting the string to URL object type prior to sending it into your NSURLRequest "request".

Try:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request2]];
```

You may also try luxsypher' answer for the string creation also, instead of the replace.

Also you may think to print out your NSString url just to make sure it is what you expect!